# Jenkins Shared Library failed to reference

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

I'm failing to reference a second groovy file in my src of my repo.

My set up is this: library name pipeline-library-demo 
[github](https://github.com/monodot/pipeline-library-demo)

I have added a second groovy file to the src folder

*app_config.groovy*

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy

def bob(opt) {
 sh "docker run --rm " +
                '--env APP_PATH="`pwd`" ' +
                '--env RELEASE=${RELEASE} ' +
                "-v \"`pwd`:`pwd`\" " +
                "-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock " +
   "docker_repo/bob:1.4.0-8" ${opt}
}

def test(name) {
  echo "Hello ${name}"
}
```

The Jenkins file I am using is:

```
pipeline {
    Library('pipeline-library-demo') _

    agent {
        node {
            label params.SLAVE
            config = new app_config()
        }
    }

    parameters {
        string(name: 'SLAVE', defaultValue: 'so_slave')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Demo') {
            steps {

                echo 'Hello World'

                sayHello 'Dave'
            }
        }
        stage('bob') {
            steps {
                config.test 'bob'
                config.bob '--help'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I am not referencing the app_config.groovy correctly and it's not finding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library call should come in starting of the jenkins file, please follow below

1. If you have added the library configuration in jenkins configuration then call should be like below:-

> @Library('pipeline-library-demo')_

2. If you want to call the library dynamically you should call like below:-

> library identifier: 'custom-lib@master', retriever:
>   modernSCM([$class:'GitSCMSource',remote:
>   'git@git.mycorp.com:my-jenkins-utils.git', credentialsId:
>   'my-private-key'])

please refer this [link](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#global-shared-libraries)

And please define package in your app_config.groovy. (ex. package com.cleverbuilder)